# Python 3: Documenting modules

Tags: python-3.x

I study how to document my code.
So, I prepared a file docstrings.py and placed it in a directory.
Now I would like to have a look at what I documented. In other words I want to type 
help(docstrings.square) and get the documentation on square function in my module.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append("C:\Users\Michael\PycharmProjects\Docstrings")
```

Result:

**SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-4: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape**

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslashes have to be doubled in [string literals](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

```
>>> sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\Michael\\PycharmProjects\\Docstrings")
```

Unless you use a *raw string*:

```
>>> sys.path.append(r"C:\Users\Michael\PycharmProjects\Docstrings")
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working. Another question. How can I use PyDoc. I read that PyDoc explores all catalogues from sys.path and finds the selected module. But how to edit sys.path for PyDoc?

Comment: Try modifying the [PYTHONPATH](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable. PyDoc should honor it.